# how to connect to the Vino server desktop from the client-side?

Tags: 16.04, networking, remote-desktop, vino, vncviewer

I read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers
to configure vino server on my ubuntu 16.04.LTS desktop.
Using other vnc servers, I used to connect to 129.254.xxx.yyy:1 (when the vnc session is 1. I can set the port).
But with this vino server, from my vnc client on my windows10 machine,
what am I supposed to connect to? how do I know the port number?
I tried vnc to 129.254.xxx.yyy:1 but didn't work.
picture below is the response seen from the client when I tried to connect to 129.254.xxx.yyy:1 but failed.
My setting on my ubuntu 16.04 looks like this :

[image]

and my response at the client side(Real vnc client, on windows 10) when I tried 129.254.xxx.yyy:0 is like this

[image]

and the message I saw when I tried 129.254.xxx.yyy:1 is like this

[image]

and the message seen at the server side (for the two incidents) is like this

[image]

What should I change at the  settings?

ADD :
After posting this question, I read http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/07/remote-access-ubuntu-16-04/ and turned off the encryption using dconf-editor. When I connect to 129.254.xxx.yyy:1, I finally got connected and could use the vnc for maybe a minute? but then the connection was closed by the server. I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. the `gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption 'false'` command doesn't work in my ubuntu16.04 version and I had to install dconf-editor and setthe remote desktop encryption there. I used 129.254.xxx.yyy:0 to connect.
During a trial I wanted to mve the server to background so I pressed ctrl-Z (thinking I would give a 'bg' comand immediately) but this maded vnc connection stall. That's why I saw 'connection refused by the server' message.
So whey you start the server , place empersand at the end like `/usr/lib/vino/ino-server &`. Now I can use vnc for my new machine using Unity desktop environment. (That's why I started with vino)